# MongoDB nested object array post query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am unable to insert data to MongoDB. I have following codes. I tried many similar answer but didn't work for me.

**Schema - question.js**

```
var questionsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
question: String,
quizdetails: String,
answers: {id:{type: String},text: { type: String }},
correctanswer: String,
feedback: String
});
```

**Router - questions.js**

```
router.post('/',jsonParser, function(req, res, next) {
 console.log(req.body);
}
```

**Returns**

```
{ question: 'quiz title',
  quizDetails: 'quiz description',
  answers:
   { '0': 'Answer 1',
     '1': 'Answer 2',
     '2': 'Answer 3',
     '3': 'Answer 4' },
  correctAnswer: 2,
  quizFeedback: 'Feedback' }
```

**Callback**

```
module.exports.createQuestion = function(newQuestion, callback) {
  newQuestion.save(callback);
}
```

Comment: What answers didn't work for you? You said you tried several.

Comment: I tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248696/post-form-data-to-array-of-existing-mongodb-document-using-express-and-mongoose and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522347/mongodb-update-objects-in-a-documents-array-nested-updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make answers type to Array:

```
answers: Array
```

then Returns document should be (document we will insert in collection)

```
{ question: 'quiz title',
  quizDetails: 'quiz description',
  answers: ['Answer 1',
            'Answer 2',
            'Answer 3',
            'Answer 4'],
  correctAnswer: 2,
  quizFeedback: 'Feedback' }
```